# Passing delimited string from dropdownlist to parameter

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist with some single-character values, and one value that is just a quoted, delimited string of multiple values:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px">
     <asp:ListItem Value="'I','A','P'">All</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="A">Active</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="I">Inactive</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="P">Prospect</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

I simply want to use ddlStatus.SelectedValue as a parameter to my datasource, which is working, for the most part, via ControlParameter:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" DefaultValue=""
    name="SearchStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" Size="12" />
```

The parameter is used in a T-SQL query:

> ...WHERE Status IN (@SearchStatus)

The single values get passed & parsed just fine, returning correct results. However the multi-valued string apparently isn't passed literally, because the records returned always match those of the first letter in the string, regardless of whether and where I add quotes to the value. (e.g. the value of 'I','A','P' selects only records where status = 'I'.)

My debugging shows that ddlStatus.SelectedValue does indeed have the value of " 'I','A','P' ", but that doesn't seem to be what gets passed to the datasource.

It seems like some additional translation or truncation is somehow happening?

Comment: Are you passing that thing to IN query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is instead of including all of the status values in your parameters, you could pass a null value into your status parameter and use the coalesce function (assuming you're connecting to Sql Server).  This would match on a specific status if it was provided, otherwise if the value of that parameter is null it just returns all records where the status column is equal to itself (always!).

```
WHERE Status = COALESCE(@SearchStatus, Status)
```

More reading on coalesce: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx